# drupal_goto argument retrival

Tags: 7, redirection, views

I am redirecting my users with the following code:

```
drupal_goto("event/registration/failed",
    array(
      'query' => array('nid'=>$submission->nid, 'sid'=>$submission->sid),
    )
);
```

On the target page I am executing the following function:

```
function _event_registration_failed($nid, $sid){
  dsm($_REQUEST);

  drupal_set_message("TESTING NID: {$nid}");
  drupal_set_message("TESTING SID: {$sid}");
}
```

My the variables in the drupal_set_message calls do not have any data.
But, the $_REQUEST object above has the data I expected.

**Is there a correct way to access argument passed with drupal_goto or is it correct to use the $_REQUEST object array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query arguments are available in `$_GET`. Drupal doesn't handle those query arguments for your menu callback; the only query argument Drupal automatically handles is `$_GET['q']`, which is the path for the requested page.

By default, `$_REQUEST` contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. Drupal uses `$_GET` for the requested page path, and I would rather use `$_GET` also in this case, just to avoid possible conflicts.

In your case, those query arguments are accessible with `$_GET['nid']`, and `$_GET['sid']`.

If you define the menu handler with code similar to the following one, then your menu callback gets those values as arguments.

```
function event_menu() {
  $items["event/registration/failed/%/%"] = array(
    // …
    'page callback' => '_event_registration_failed',
    'page arguments' => array(3, 4),
  );

  return $items;
}

function _event_registration_failed($nid, $sid) {
  // …
}
```

You could get the node object, instead of the node ID, if you use the following code.

```
function event_menu() {
  $items["event/registration/failed/%node/%"] = array(
    // …
    'page callback' => '_event_registration_failed',
    'page arguments' => array(3, 4),
  );

  return $items;
}

function _event_registration_failed($node, $sid) {
  // …
}
```